# How to configure buckminster to not use default JDK to compile during build?

Tags: eclipse, jenkins, buckminster

I'm creating a build job on jenkins, the main part of it is a buckminster launch:

[image: buckminster configuration on jenkins job]

The job requires Java 1.8 and it's integrated JavaFX. The servers `JAVA_HOME` points to a Java 1.7 and all other jobs use that JDK.
So I configured a 1.8 JDK in the Jenkins system configuration and added it to the specific job:

[image]

Now when I run the job I get the following log (anonymised):

> $ C:/Progra~1/Java/jdk1.8.0_40\bin\java.exe -Dbuckminster.output.root=PATH_TO_OUTPUT\buckminster.output -Dbuckminster.temp.root=PATH_TO_TEMP\buckminster.temp -Dworkspace=PATH_TO_WORKSPACE -Dqualifier=${QUALIFIER} -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -jar PATH_TO_BUCKMINSTER\buckminster4.4.0\buckminster\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar -application org.eclipse.buckminster.cmdline.headless -data PATH_TO_WORKSPACE --loglevel info -S PATH_TO_COMMANDS\commands.txt
>   INFO:  setpref 'targetPlatformPath=PATH_TO_TARGETPLATFORM/targetPlatform'
>   INFO:  import 'PATH_TO_CQUERY/site.cquery'
>   INFO:  Import complete.
>   INFO:  build
>   Error: file PATH_TO_CLASS\TargetController.java, line 11: The import javafx cannot be resolved

... lot more of there errors

> Warning: file PATH_TO_MANIFEST\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF, line 98: The JRE container on the classpath is not a perfect match to the 'JavaSE-1.8' execution environment

So this indicates that the "build" is not using the configured JDK 1.8 eventhough it is beeing started with "`C:/Progra~1/Java/jdk1.8.0_40\bin\java.exe`".

The question is how do I configure buckminster to use my 1.8 JDK?

Answer (score 0):

can you try the answer i specified:

[How to trigger Jenkins builds remotely and to pass parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20359810/how-to-trigger-jenkins-builds-remotely-and-to-pass-paramter?nah=1#28816352)

I mean even JDK can be parameterised, let me know.

Comment: The build itself is using the configured JDK 1.8 (see second print screen and log C:/Progra~1/Java/jdk1.8.0_40\bin\java.exe). To problem is that buckminster inside is not using this configuration for building (guessing buckminster just takes the default JDK of the system).