# How to trigger a jenkins job remotely which has a list subversion tag as a parameter

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a requirement where i need to trigger the build jobs remotely using curl command. I am unable to pass the branch/tag name as a parameter to trigger the build.

I used the below command :

```
& $CURLEXE -k -X POST $dst_job_url --user username:token --data-urlencode json='{"parameters": [{"name":"branch","branch":"branches"}]}'
```

If i run the above command it was triggers the build for the trunk ( default ).

Answer (score 0):

You omitted the URL, so it's hard to be certain.  Jenkins has two urls for building: "build" and "buildWithParameters".  If you're not using buildWithParameters, switching to it will probably help.

See:
[How to trigger Jenkins builds remotely and to pass parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20359810/how-to-trigger-jenkins-builds-remotely-and-to-pass-parameters)