# Passing parameters from bitbucket web hooks to jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket, hook, bitbucket-server

Issue I am facing is the following:

- I want to trigger a job which is setup on Jenkins from BitBucket (on push)
- I want to tigger it and to pass parameters
- Trigger job without params is working, but as soon as I add params, nothing is triggered and I don't get any logs.

Here is my url on Jenkins (which is working)

```
http://someJenkinsInstance/bitbucket-hook/
```

And here is url that I would like to use (at least use params)

```
http://someJenkinsInstance/bitbucket-hook/buildWithParameters?BRANCH=master&ENVIRONMENT=dev
```

On Jenkins side, I'm using the plugin "Bitbucket hook" and in BitBucket plugin is "Post web hooks".

Note: I am using Bitbucket server not cloud version.

Comment: You are probably looking for the [Remote Access API](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API).

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20359810/how-to-trigger-jenkins-builds-remotely-and-to-pass-parameters

Comment: @YuriG. Well I checked this solution but problem is with latest version of Jenkins, we can't call Job by url using GET. It must be using POST. So my build is not triggered.

Comment: the fastest way will be to create your own hook script that will make a POST request and to put it in the repo

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to add parameter in web hook. Here I am considering a generic web hook

```
https://[COMPANY_NAME].com/generic-webhook-trigger/invoke?token=[TOKEN_NAME]&name=testing&type=pool_request
```

To get the result of **name** and **type** you need to setup pipeline job and select generic web hook trigger then select request parameter and enter **name** and another one is **type**
Screenshot
[image]

Now all you need to create a bash script or Jenkins/groovy so lets consider Jenkins groovy file and paste the below and try to trigger you web hook.

```
node()
{
    print "name = ${name}"
    print "Type ${type}"
}
```

Similar you can create a parameterised web hook for parameterized job

```
JENKINS_URL/job/ParameterizedJobName/buildWithParameters?token=TOKEN_NAME&name=testing&type=testing
```

And following parameters to your job
[image]

Then select Execute shell and write following code

```
echo $name $type
```

An example with generic web hook job (not parameterized job):- https://www.svastikkka.com/2021/01/how-to-pass-parameter-in-webhook.html