# Is it possible that "Build now" runs a specific branch or multiple branches?

Tags: git, jenkins, github

It seems like that the "Build now" runs a single branch, the default branch of the project, although I defined two branch specifiers in the configuration of "Source Code Management".

Is there any chance to get it to run several branches or a specific branch?

Answer (score 1):

You can make your job parameterized, add string parameter **BRANCH** and set "**Branches to build**" is equal $BRANCH

[Branches to build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGFB0.png)

Answer (score 1):

Is your build "parameterized"? If not, I suggest to add "branch" as a parameter and configure ${branch} in "Source Code Management" configuration.

Something like this :

[image]

On rebuild, you can specify which branch to build.

[image]

If you have set "concurrent build", multiple rebuilds can be triggered with different branches as parameter.

Comment: Thanks :) Can this work together with GitHub Hook Triggers?

Comment: I haven't used GitHub hooks. But if its like triggering a build remotely, say through a hook when a push happens, you can use something like this : 

"http: // JENKINS_SERVER_ADDRESS/job/YOUR_JOB_NAME/buildWithParameters?myparam=myparam_value"

Refer more here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20359810/how-to-trigger-jenkins-builds-remotely-and-to-pass-parameters