# Automate Jenkins Pipeline to run multiple times

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline

I am using a Jenkins pipeline to process files for a UAT. 
Stages are like:

1. Get the files
2. Put them in the right directory
3. Run bash script
4. Run another bash script
5. Run another bash script
6. Send results

I would like to be able to run 1 or more times this pipeline based on the number of EODs I want to run.

So if EODs are:

```
20180720, 20180721, 20180722
```

I want the pipeline to run 3 times.

So;

```
for eod in '20180720, 20180721, 20180722'
run pipeline $eod
done
```

I know you can launch it with the url and parameters like John mentions below, and I am looking for a more simple solution, if there is any.

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you looked at this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20359810/how-to-trigger-jenkins-builds-remotely-and-to-pass-parameters

Comment: Hi John, Thanks for your reaction! I already have looked at this option, and though it might work, I am hoping there is a more simple solution where you can just loop trough pipeline's.

Comment: Where do you get the EOD values from? Without knowing any more details I’d say you can either use a simple loop or trigger another build of yourself using the build step.

Comment: Hi Joerg, the EOD values should be parsed manually for it changes with every UAT you run. So lets say you have a UAT for 20180720, 20180721, 20180722, you pass these arguments once and it will loop trough those dates. 
Per EOD you need a whole pipeline and it should start after the last EOD is finished.

Comment: Parameters is the simplest solution you can get... just wrap your pipeline in a loop so that you can iterate for each EOD.