# Write code to trigger a jenkins build from slack

Tags: jenkins, slack

i am currently facing this challenge. I Need to write a code to convert the slack commands from slack channel to  REST API payload and trigger the JOB with info(Reponame, Reponame, Branch Name, Artifact Version, NTuserID/UserName). Any ideas on where and how to start this?

Answer (score 0):

The general outline would be: follow slack's documentation on how to receive slash commands: https://api.slack.com/slash-commands#app_command_handling and then whenever you receive a command, make a request to your Jenkins server with the desired parameters filled out, as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/20360774/922613

The exact infrastructure for how to implement this pattern is up to you.