# Not getting parameter value while using Jenkins job trigger using URL

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

here I'm triggering my Jenkins job from URL with some parameters and trying to get that parameter values in my pipeline script

Here is the command with URL:

```
curl -k -v -u user:secrate http://IP:PORT/jenkins/job/GROUP-GROUP/view/Deploy-Jobs/job/Automate-deployment-JOB/buildWithParameters?token=MY-TOCKEN&MY-PARAMETOR=some_value
```

Pipeline script of jenkins JOB:

```
pipeline {
    agent none
    stages{
        stage ('test') {
            agent { label 'My-Slave' }
            steps {
                println "$MY-PARAMETOR"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here I'm able to trigger my Jenkins build but not getting the value in pipeline script

Getting the following error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: MY-PARAMETOR for class: groovy.lang.Binding
```

Can any one please help me on this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the parameter is defined in the pipeline first.
See:

- https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parameters
- https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API

(Somewhat duplicate to [How to trigger Jenkins builds remotely and to pass parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20359810/how-to-trigger-jenkins-builds-remotely-and-to-pass-parameters))