# How to automatically configure jenkins user input stage from remote build?

Tags: node.js, jenkins, aws-lambda

I am trying to automatically kick off a jenkins build through my node lambda. I have achieved this but now I'm getting stuck where one stage in my pipeline requires user input. is there a way to do this automatically?

I had a look at `buildWithParameters` but that doesn't seem to have worked.

any one ran into this issue before?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to trigger Jenkins builds remotely and to pass parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20359810/how-to-trigger-jenkins-builds-remotely-and-to-pass-parameters)

Comment: @karthikeayan I've already explained I tried to use `buildWithParameters` and it did not work

Answer (score 0):

You can use a input step, ref: https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-input-step/

Comment: yeh but this isn't for trigger from a remote build is it?

Comment: okay, you mean you are triggering a job on remote host, possibly by using a rest call/remote-access-api and you need to pass some parameters, as per their documentation (ref:https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API) `buildWithParameters` should work but apparently it doesn't.

Comment: this may help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20359810/how-to-trigger-jenkins-builds-remotely-and-to-pass-parameters?noredirect=1&lq=1