# Jenkins: start build of multiple project, based on Boolean parameter

Tags: jenkins, parameters

I have a job with "This project is parameterized" checked. I use "Boolean Parameter". I have such parameters - 50 of them in this job. Each param contains the name of another project and "Default Value" checked or unchecked. I need, when I start this job, a check to be made. If the value is checked, I need the job, which name is in the "Name" field to be triggered and built. The unchecked object needs no build at the moment. Below are some images for clarity. I cannot use any plugins since I do not have permission to install them. As a hint I was told that it is possible to be done with ssh??? but I am not sure about that.

I see that there is this option called "Build other projects", but I need to build only the one having checkboxes ticked. After a whole day spent in research, I was not able to understand how to configure this relation

Comment: Your parameterized project is of which type (freestyle, pipeline (declarative or scripted), ...)?

Comment: Hey, Thank you for joining here :). It should be a freestyle project since I am missing the Advanced and the Pipeline tabs in the configuration. It also should be declarative. I think my images are missing from the post, so I will try to put them again here. I am still nowhere here with this task.

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rC6iX.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXNif.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWE2k.png

Comment: Do you have the possibility to choose **Conditional step (single)** when clicking on **ADD BUILD STEP** under **Build** section/tab?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have the option you are asking for. These are the options from the dropdown menu in the Build section:

- Execute Windows batch command
- Execute shell
- Inject environment variables
- Invoke top-level Maven targets
- Run with timeout
- Set build status to "pending" on GitHub commit

Comment: **Conditional step (single)** is a plugin. Since you can not install any plugins, I do not have any other ideas how to get your use case work :/

Comment: Actually it should work with no plugins either. This is something I am trying to do from few days now, but with no success so far. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20359810/how-to-trigger-jenkins-builds-remotely-and-to-pass-parameters
I created a dummyjob1 to test the "Trigger builds remotely". But no matter how I change the trigger URL, the dummyjob1 is just not triggered.